# Where use HiddenFor to post Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I created a view using a ViewModel binding a `Dictionary<int, string>` to a `@Html.DropDownListFor()`. My issue is on the `[HttpPost]` method : my ViewModel return an empty dictionary. I tried to use `@Html.HiddenFor()` method to keep the data, but it does not worked.

Am I wrong on the use of the HiddenFor method ??

Here is the view :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset class="fieldset-required">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Dictionary.Keys)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Dictionary.Values)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedId, 
              new SelectList(Model.Dictionary, "Key", "Value"), "-- Select --")

        <input type="submit" value="Confirm" class="validation-button" />    

    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: You cannot bind an input to a collection. And why in the world would you want to post that back anyway - if you need to return the view because `ModelState` is invalid, then you just build the `Dictionary` again as you did in the GET method.

Comment: And stop using a `Dictionary` - you view model should contain a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Options` property, and then the view is just `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedId, Model.Options, "-- Select --")`